Chart time series extract points NDVI Landsat
I'm getting an error, stating that I can't generate the graph of NDVI values points by date of the image. How can I fix it?

Error generating chart: Collection.first: Error in
map(ID=LC08_191031_20220805):  Image.select: Band pattern 'ndvi' did
not match any bands.  Available bands: [B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7,
B8, B9, B10, B11, QA_PIXEL, QA_RADSAT, SAA, SZA, VAA, VZA]

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b0a5fb2a0a851ee3749c9b1f7e90ecd
    // load the LC08 dataset
    var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT')
   .filterDate("2022-01-01", "2022-12-31").filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 20))

   // add NDVI
    function addNDVI(image) {
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
    return image.addBands(ndvi)
    }

    var points = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([12.487749926662959, 41.88485067969689])),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([12.492396084115729, 41.890305914470154]))
    ])

    var timeSeries = points
    .map(timeSeriesForPoint)
    .flatten()

    var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
    features: timeSeries, 
    xProperty: 'date', 
    yProperty: 'ndvi', 
    seriesProperty: 'point'
    }) 
    
    print(timeSeries)
    print(chart)
    Map.addLayer(points, null, 'points')


    function timeSeriesForPoint(point) {
    return S2
    .filterBounds(point.geometry())
    .map(function (image) {
    return extractNdvi(image, point)
    })
    }

    function extractNdvi(image, point) {
    var ndvi = image
    .select('ndvi')
    .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
    geometry: point.geometry(), 
    scale: 30
    })
    .getNumber('ndvi')
    return ee.Feature(null, {
    point: point.geometry().coordinates().join(', '),
    ndvi: ndvi,
    date: image.date()
    })
    }


Coding questions here require code. Removing the code is not likely to result in fewer close votes.
